# Как вывести данные о пользователе когда он переходит в свой аккаунт?

Tags: python, sqlite3, flet

Я делаю приложение на flet с бд sqlite3 и не понимаю как мне выводить данные о пользователе когда он заходит в свой профиль. Как я должен обратиться именно к тому пользователю который зашёл в свой аккаунт, а не к другим.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
conn = sqlite3.connect('название-твоей-базы.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Ищем пользователя по его id (Вместо 123 id пользователя который нам нужен)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 123")

# Получаем результат
user = cursor.fetchone()

# Закрываем соединение с базой данных
conn.close()

# Теперь переменная `user` содержит результат запроса
print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, password TEXT, info TEXT)')

#далее используйте TextField во flet чтобы получить login и password

cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="{login}" AND password="{password}"')

data = cursor.fetchone()
if data:
    info = data[3] #информация
    user_id = data[0] #id пользователя
else:
    #пользователь не найден
```

Также рекомендую посмотреть видео на ютубе про вход и регистрация в flet. [На английском](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWUM1Yx79mE&pp=ygUbZmxldCDRgNC10LPQuNGB0YLRgNCw0YbQuNGP) и [на русском](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JE8e7-IXJTA&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFVZr9lLryYHSbAbrn3YJGbE&index=4)